# Inline Width for Login Area, that overrides the default in CSS

Tags: html, css, background, width

Please i have an issue with my form background image display. It works well for other forms on the website, but i'll like to apply some height and width to the login area of the form, it actually displays the image but the width is too much. If i adjust the CSS width, it dosent dispaly well for others. So can i do a sort of inline width for only login area.

Thanks for your time and patience, I most appreciate it.

**CSS**

```
   form {
   background-color: red;
   width: 550px;
   background: url(../images/back.gif)            top right:
   }
```

**HTML**

```
          <form action="form.php" method     = "post">
    Username: <input type = "text" name      = "username">

    Password: <input type = "password"       name = "password" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an id to the form like this

```
<form id="login-id" action="form.php" method     = "post">
Username: <input type = "text" name  = "username">
Password: <input type = "password" name = "password" >
```

Then in the css file:

```
#login-id 
{
width: XXpx;
}
```

or you can modify the elements themselvesas well by giving id's to the inputs

```
<input id="form-user" type = "text" name = "username">

css:
#form-user { width:50px; }
```

inline:        input type = "text" name  = "username" style="width:[some px]px;"

(doesn't let me put it in with <   > for some reason, you'll have to put it there yourself)

Comment: Thanks the first solution looks cleaner and progressive.